# How to find files whose name is not exact in python

Tags: python, file

I created a script to find the images that have the codes that are in an excel file and copy them to another folder.

For example in my excel file I have 1856.jpg, 532.jpg and so on. In the folder that I specify, I have those images and up to that point the program works and copies what is in the excel file.

The problem comes when in my excel file there is an image 674.jpg so I have it in my folder but in this way 456_674_542.jpg I mean in a single photo there are 3 codes, how do I do it in that case?

​

```
import​ ​os​, ​shutil​, ​xlrd 
  
 
 #We create an empty list to fill with the codes later 
 ​files_to_find​ ​=​ [] 
 ​lista_imagenes_total​=​[] 
 ​ruta_destino​ ​=​ ​'C:/Users/Albin Rodriguez/Pictures/carpeta4'​ ​ 
  
 ​#We open the excel file and fetch all the codes to the list. 
 ​data​ ​=​ ​xlrd​.​open_workbook​(​input​(​"Digite el nombre del archivo excel y su extension: "​)) 
 ​sheet1​ ​=​ ​data​.​sheet_by_index​(​0​) 
 ​for​ ​i​ ​in​ ​range​(​sheet1​.​nrows​): 
 ​    ​files_to_find​.​append​(​sheet1​.​cell_value​(​i​, ​0​)) 
 ​     
 ​#we search the images in this path 
 ​for​ ​root​, ​dirs​, ​files​ ​in​ ​os​.​walk​(​'C:/Users/Albin Rodriguez/Desktop/FOTOS PRODUCTOS/'​): 
 ​    ​for​ ​_file​ ​in​ ​files​: 
 ​        ​if​ ​_file​ ​in​ ​files_to_find​: 
 ​            ​print​ (​f'​{​_file​}​ Encontrado en esta ruta: '​ ​+​ ​str​(​root​)) ​# If we find it, this will print the path 
 ​            ​shutil​.​copy​(​os​.​path​.​abspath​(​root​ ​+​ ​'/'​ ​+​ ​_file​), ​'C:/Users/Albin Rodriguez/Pictures/carpeta4'​) 
 ​        ​lista_imagenes_total​.​append​(​_file​) 
  
 ​#We check which files were not found
 ​for​ ​elementos​ ​in​ ​files_to_find​: 
 ​    ​if​ ​elementos​ ​not​ ​in​ ​lista_imagenes_total​: 
 ​        ​print​(​f"El archivo ​{​elementos​}​ no fue encontrado!"​)
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to just call find (returns the index of the searched pattern):

```py
file_name = "456_674_542.jpg"
file_name_in_excel = "674"
if file_name.find(file_name_in_excel) != -1:
    print(file_name)
```

If you need more special cases use regex.